# Extract digits from string by condition

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to extract digits from a short string, base on a condition that the digits is in front of a character (`S` flag).

example and result:

```
> string = '10M26S'
> 26

> string = '18S8M10S'
> [18,10] OR 28

> string = '7S29M'
> 7
```

I can split the string to a list to get the individual element,

```
result = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby('18S8M10S', str.isalpha)]
> ['18', 'S', '8', 'M', '10', 'S']
```

but how could I just get the `18` and `10`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with the regex `r'(\d+)S'`. This matches all digits before a capital `S`.

```
>>> string = '10M26S'
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+)S',string)
['26']
>>> string = '18S8M10S'
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+)S',string)
['18', '10']
>>> string = '7S29M'
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+)S',string)
['7']
```

To get integer output, you can convert them in a list comp or use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> list(map(int,['18', '10']))
[18, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html).

```
import re
regex = r"(\d+)S"
match = re.search(regex, '10M26S')
print(match.group(1))  # '26'
```

Comment: thanks for help. for a string: 18S8M10S，it only prints 18 (the first matching digits)

Comment: Try using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.search). It returns a list of matches, rather than just a single one

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

[int(m) for m in re.findall(r'(\d+)S', "input10string30")]
```

this should do the trick